# How should I optimize MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a query like below:

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, u.ssoProfile, SUM(p.number) AS totalPoints, u.vip 
FROM `user` u
LEFT JOIN `point` p
ON u.id = p.user
AND p.expiryDate > NOW()
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.firstName ASC, u.lastName ASC, u.email ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

I have added indexes

- User table 1 index (`firstName, lastName, email`) in hope it will speed up `ORDER BY`
- Point table 2 indexes (`user`, `expireDate`)

When I do an `EXPLAIN`

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, u.ssoProfile, SUM(p.number) AS totalPoints, u.vip  FROM `user` u LEFT JOIN `point` p ON u.id = p.user AND p.expiryDate > NOW() GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY u.firstName ASC, u.lastName ASC, u.email ASC LIMIT 10\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: u
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY,username,email,ssoId,token,referralCode
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
        Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: p
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I think the problem is the `ORDER BY`? Removing it speeds things up. But how do I optimize this?

**UPDATE**

I managed to optimize the query like

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, u.ssoProfile, u.vip, SUM(p.number) AS totalPoints
FROM (
    SELECT u.id
    FROM user u
    ORDER BY u.firstName ASC, u.lastName ASC, u.email ASC
    LIMIT 460000, 10
) u2
INNER JOIN user u
ON u2.id = u.id
LEFT JOIN `point` p
ON u.id = p.user
AND p.expiryDate > NOW()
GROUP BY u.id;
```

That subquery can make use of the composite index on `firstName, lastName, email`. I also added index on `p.expireDate` and `p.user`. That subquery was "inspired" by http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/

Comment: What's your current time taken for query output?

Comment: It will probably be quicker if you use a variable instead of `NOW()`: `DECLARE @DateNow DATETIME = NOW()` and use that in the comparison

Comment: Could it be, that u.id and p.user are of different data type or that you are testing with too few data? When you use too few data, MySQL decides that it's cheaper to do a full table scan.

Comment: @fancyPants, yes looks like you are right, they are of different sizes. INT(10) and INT(11) it matters isit?

Comment: No, that doesn't matter.

Comment: `LIMIT 10` and `LIMIT 460000, 10` are different -- which one do you need to optimize?  Do you have more than 460K rows in `user`?

Comment: The real answer may be to remove `LEFT` if it is not really needed.